# How to sort an array by numbers in strings?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```js
[
  'B3', 'B4', 'B5',
 
  'B6', 'C3', 'C4',
 
  'C5', 'C6', 'D3',
 
  'D4', 'D5', 'D6'
]
```

I need to sort it by the number in each string (in ascending order). The number can be one/double-digit/triple-digit.

Here's what the final array should look like:

```js
[
  'B3', 'C3', 'D3',
 
  'B4', 'C4', 'D4',
 
  'B5', 'C5', 'D5',
 
  'B6', 'C6', 'D6'
]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there will always be only one letter at the beginning - then here is the solution:

```js
const input = [
    'B3', 'B4', 'B5',
    'B6', 'C3', 'C4',
    'C5', 'C645', 'D3',
    'D4', 'D532', 'D6'
];

console.log(sort(input));

function sort(array) {
   return array.sort((a, b) => {
       const aVal = parseInt(a.slice(1), 10);
       const bVal = parseInt(b.slice(1), 10);

       if (aVal < bVal) {
           return -1;
       }
       if (aVal > bVal) {
           return 1;
       }

       return 0;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to the sort method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

And how you can pass a function in for values comparison as a criteria to sort the elements :)

```js
const myArray = [
  'B3', 'B4', 'B5',
 
  'B6', 'C3', 'C4',
 
  'C5', 'C6', 'D3',
 
  'D4', 'D5', 'D6'
]

const sortedArray = myArray.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
console.log(sortedArray)
```

Comment: From the description: "The number can be one/double-digit/triple-digit.". And you're using only 1 digit

Comment: then if  the OP doesnt even post his attempt, should post at least the code that defines his problem. Your answer is much better though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` method of array with custom comparator function as:

```js
const arr = [
  'B3', 'B4', 'B5',
  'B6', 'C3', 'C4',
  'C5', 'C6', 'D3',
  'D4', 'D5', 'D6',
];

const result = arr.sort((a, b) => +a.match(/\d+/) - +b.match(/\d+/));
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
const sortByNum = arr => {
    let newArr = arr.map(item => {
        return {
            letter: item[0],
            number: item.substr(1, item.length),
        };
    });
    newArr.sort((numA, numB) => numA.number - numB.number);
    return newArr.map(item => {
        return (item.letter + item.number);
    });
};
```

its basically dividing each string into key/value pairs, sorting them by number, then joining them back into strings.